# How to change my desktop background via bash?

Tags: bash, gnome, desktop-background, gsettings

I am trying to set up [this](https://github.com/anirudhajith/process-wallpaper/blob/master/README.md) script to change my desktop background, but

```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$WALLPAPER_PATH"
```

is not working. There is no error message, but no effect.

I have tried running

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/username/wallpaper.jpg"
```

in terminal, but my background is not changed.

I ran `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme` which returns 'default' and changing the command to `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file:///home/username/wallpaper.jpg"` has no effect.

EDIT: I found what was going wrong. gsettings was being run from the anaconda shell.

Comment: For me, running the command immediately changes the background. I cannot see any error in what you attempted.

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu? Which DE are you currently running?

Comment: @muru I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, freshly installed at the beginning of September.